# php encypting password and then verifiing doesnt work

Tags: php

So this is how I encrypt my password.

```
$password_encrypted = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

And this is how I get the value and check it:

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    session_start();

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // username and password sent from form 

        $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['uname']);
        $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['psw']); 

        $result = mysqli_query(
            $db,
            "SELECT password FROM interna_dostop WHERE up_name = '$myusername'");

        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $hash = $row['password'];
        echo $hash;
        echo $mypassword;
        echo $myusername;

        if (password_verify('$mypassword','$hash')) {
            header('Location: another.php'); exit;
        } else {
            echo 'Invalid password.';
        }
    }
?>
```

Now here is the funny part. This returns false. But if I enter in password_verify ('mypass', 'encrypted_pass') I get true?

Any ideas?

Comment: You *hash* passwords, not *encrypt*.

Comment: ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: password_verify('$mypassword','$hash') replace it with password_verify($mypassword,$hash). Single quote is not needed here.

Comment: What size is the column where you're storing the hash? Can you share the code where you store the passwords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `$mypassword` and `$hash` in with single quotes to `password_verify()`. No need for the single quotes.

```
password_verify($mypassword,$hash)
```

Comment: You in-fact can't use single quotes because of string interpolation in PHP.

`echo '$mypassword';`
resolves to `$mypassword`

Comment: Not within the function, though. It will evaluate `'$mypassword'` as a literal string, which is (most likely) not the correct password, nor would the string literal `'$hash'` be the correct hash. This function evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

Variables inside password_verify is not interpreted as they are within single quotes. You need to remove the single quotes.

`if (password_verify($mypassword, $hash)) {`